# How can we remotely monitor VMware ESXI?

Tags: monitoring, vmware-esxi

We have VMware ESXi on several servers, how can we remotely monitor for problems with hard drives, RAM, power supply or network cards?

Answer (score 4):

You don't mention what make/model your servers are but if they're on the HCL then there will be some hardware alerting built right in that you can keep an eye on via VSClient or via a vCenter. Some manufacturers have extended hardware alerting drivers that they can let you have (often in a custom made installer for ESXi) which can give give you much more granular detail.

Answer (score 2):

If your server has some sot of remote management you could use that, also you could use the SNMP feature of ESXi if you have the proper licensing. If you are running on newer dell servers the idrac is great.

Answer (score 1):

If your running HP, you can always use insight manager.

Answer (score 1):

i use pysphere http://code.google.com/p/pysphere/  with zabbix and it works great

example:

```
for h in props.runtime.healthSystemRuntime.systemHealthInfo.numericSensorInfo:
            print h.name
            print h.currentReading
        self.server.disconnect()

worked like charm...

System Board 9 Power Meter - Device enabled
44800
System Board 7 Temp 25 - Normal
4600
System Internal Expansion Board 13 Temp 24 - Normal
8300
System Internal Expansion Board 12 Temp 23 - Normal
7900
Power Domain 1 Temp 22 - Normal
300
Processor 3 Temp 21 - Normal
```

Answer (score 0):

Am currently using HPSIM with the HPServers, and there is a nice little plugin for VCenter that will allow you to see up to date information regarding temperatures, fan speeds, power status, etc., all from within VCenter.

SIM also well send out emails or alerts when a problem is detected.  For example, when a power supply fan is having an issue, or temperature is up in a zone, SIM will send me an email.

I haven't tried it it, but you should be able to set up something similar with the Alarms/Definitions/Actions section of VCenter.

Since we are largely (almost completely!) HP shop, I can't speak to other vendors gear.  However, we just got seeded a Dell M1000e and some blades, so I hope to learn more about the management and monitoring of that gear really soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use CIM to monitor ESX and ESXi. See: http://blogs.vmware.com/esxi/2010/04/hardware-health-monitoring-via-cim.html